# Convert a character string in Format "%B-%d-%Y-%I:%M-%p" into a Date with Format "%Y%m%d" in R

Tags: r, date

My data set contains dates like this: `my_date = c("December 02, 2017 at 07:33PM")`.

The Format should be `"%B-%d-%Y-%I:%M-%p"`.

I already removed the "at" with:

```r
library(tm)
stopwords = c("at")
my_date = removeWords(my_date, stopwords).
```

How can I now convert the date into my desired format. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```r
psx <- as.POSIXct("December 02, 2017 at 07:33PM", format = "%B %d, %Y at %I:%M%p")
psx
# [1] "2017-12-02 19:33:00 EST"
format(psx, format = "%B-%d-%Y-%I:%M-%p")
# [1] "December-02-2017-07:33-PM"
```